# BHO Handle OnSubmit event

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, events, bho

Basically I want to develop a BHO that validates certain fields on a form and auto-places disposable e-mails in the appropriate fields (more for my own knowledge). So in the DOCUMENTCOMPLETE event I have this:

```
for(long i = 0; i < *len; i++)
{
    VARIANT* name = new VARIANT();
    name->vt = VT_I4;
    name->intVal = i;
    VARIANT* id = new VARIANT();
    id->vt = VT_I4;
    id->intVal = 0;
    IDispatch* disp = 0;
    IHTMLFormElement* form = 0;
    HRESULT r = forms->item(*name,*id,&disp);
    if(S_OK != r)
    {
        MessageBox(0,L"Failed to get form dispatch",L"",0);// debug only
        continue;
    }
    disp->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLFormElement2,(void**)&form);
    if(form == 0)
    {
        MessageBox(0,L"Failed to get form element from dispatch",L"",0);// debug only
        continue;
    }

    // Code to listen for onsubmit events here...         
}
```

How would I use the IHTMLFormElement interface to listen for the onsubmit event?

Comment: There are a bunch of things about your code that I would change.  First: don't create new VARIANTS, just declare them on the stack and pass them normally.  Either way, make sure you call VariantClear() on them when you are done with them so they are released properly.  Also, consider using SUCCEEDED(hr) instead of S_OK != r...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the pointer to the element you want to sink events for, you would `QueryInterface()` it for `IConnectionPointContainer` and then connect to that:

```
REFIID riid = DIID_HTMLFormElementEvents2;
CComPtr<IConnectionPointContainer> spcpc;
HRESULT hr = form->QueryInterface(IID_IConnectionPointContainer, (void**)&spcpc);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    CComPtr<IConnectionPoint> spcp;
    hr = spcpc->FindConnectionPoint(riid, &spcp);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        DWORD dwCookie;
        hr = pcp->Advise((IDispatch *)this, &dwCookie);
    }
}
```

Some notes:

1. You probably want to cache `dwCookie` and `cpc`, since you need them later when you call `pcp->Unadvise()` to disconnect the sink.
2. In the call to `pcp->Advise()` above, I pass this.  You can use any object you have that implements `IDispatch`, which may or may not be this object.  Design left to you.
3. `riid` will be the event dispinterface you want to sink.  In this case, you probably want `DIID_HTMLFormElementEvents2`.

Here's how to disconnect:

```
pcp->Unadvise(dwCookie);
```

Let me know if you have further questions.

Edit-1:

Yeah, that DIID was wrong.  It should be: `DIID_HTMLFormElementEvents2`.

Here is how I found it:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\PlatformSDK>findstr /spin /c:"Events2" *.h | findstr /i /c:"form"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The only problem I'm having is that "DIID_HTMLFormEvents2" isn't declared anywhere. I tried searching google but it didn't bring up anything. Any ideas how to fix this?